# Standard ML programming, array function

Tags: arrays, ml

In ML I have an array of chars! I am trying to find an array function in order to give the function the char #"T" and returns me the position of this element in array. I tried the find function and it doesn't work like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findi` from the `Array` structure will do what you want. For an array of type `'a array`, `findi` takes a `(int * 'a) -> bool` and a `'a array` and returns an `(int * 'a) option`. So if you want to take a character and just return the character's position, you just need figure out the appropriate arguments to pass to `findi` and the appropriate way to interpret the result.

So for instance:

```
- fun findPos char = (Option.map (fn (i,_) => i)) o (Array.findi (fn (_,c) => c = char));
stdIn:2.65 Warning: calling polyEqual
val findPos = fn : ''a -> ''a array -> int option
- findPos #"c" (Array.fromList (explode "abcdef"));
val it = SOME 2 : int option
- findPos #"z" (Array.fromList (explode "abcdef"));
val it = NONE : int option
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!it is not a homework assignment but i need for a program that i am writting in ml in which the compliler doesnt accept the use of findi as correct.Can you give me some more clarification in order to return the character's position?

Comment: Sure. Added an example of how you can do it.